# Update table with window function

Tags: sql, postgresql, amazon-redshift, window-functions

I've table in Redshift with duplicated row that i want to delete,

for that I created filed Id and i want to update him to delete duplicated rows
I'm trying to run this query but it doesn't work

```
update mr_usage
set id=row_number () over (partition by uid,date(ts),title order by ts)
```

I received the following error:

ERROR: cannot use window function in UPDATE

I'm looking for a way to update that field

Comment: Maybe put the row_number() and friends into a subquwery, and update from that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The other possible solution (without CTE) is using `UPDATE .. FROM` syntax with subquery directly

```
UPDATE mr_usage outer
SET id = sub.new_id
FROM (
    SELECT 
        id, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY uid, date(ts), title ORDER BY ts) AS new_id
    FROM
        mr_usage
) sub
WHERE outer.id = sub.id
```

But it is also available since PostgreSQL 8.4.

Answer (score 2):

You can try a [CTE](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/queries-with.html) to achieve this, although such an UPDATE won't remove any duplicate rows.

```
WITH n AS (
  SELECT
    id AS current_id,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY uid, date(ts), title ORDER BY ts) AS new_id
  FROM
    mr_usage
)
UPDATE
  mr_usage
SET
  id = n.new_id
FROM
  n
WHERE
  mr_usage.id = n.current_id;
```

Comment: i received the following error: ERROR: syntax error at or near "UPDATE"

Comment: If redshift is based on pg-8.0, there will be no CTEs and no window functions. (these were both introduced in pg-8.4, IIRC)

Comment: i can running windows function , can't say that about CTE since i don't know that, there is other option to do that?

Comment: @user3600910 [look at my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32994087/5404196) for different approach.

Comment: CTE (or WITH clause) is supported in Redshift with few limitations, refer the documentation http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_WITH_clause.html