# Table Column Not Updating

Tags: sql, postgresql

```
update 
    table_1 as q
set 
    q_sequence = (row_number() OVER(
            PARTITION BY
            q.account_uid
            ,q.c_c_uid
            ,q.a_uid
             order by q.a_time ASC) as new
```

This does not work, I get the following error message:

> Query 1: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "as" LINE 10:     order by
> q.a_time ASC) as new

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are incorrectly using the `as` keyword here.

`as` is used for aliasing a table or a column in a select statement:
https://www.w3schools.com/mysql/mysql_alias.asp

Removing `as new` should solve you syntax error.

Comment: Query 1: ERROR:  window functions are not allowed in UPDATE
LINE 6:  question_taken_sequence = (row_number() OVER(
                                    ^

Comment: Got any other suggestions?

Comment: This might help: https://learnsql.com/blog/window-functions-not-allowed-in-where/
Further: window functions are only allowed in select statements - This might also help:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32993245/update-table-with-window-function